# Warning: Illegal string offset php sql

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

I have a problem when I use foreach loop to browse the result of a sql request i got this error queryWarning: Illegal string offset when i use foreach:
can anybody help me please, I'm lost

Here is my code:

connexion.php:

```
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=rep', '******', '******');
```

sendMail.php

```
include("connexion.php");
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$sql= $bdd->query('SELECT count(id) as id from inci where retour="0" AND 
atelier="test"');
       $data = $sql->fetch();

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               

$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host = '******';                   
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = '******';                 
$mail->Password = '*******';                     
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
$mail->Port = 587;                                    
$mail->setFrom('******');
$mail->addAddress('******', 'name');     

$mail->Subject = ' valider';
$mail->Body    = "
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>

                        <th> Destinataire     |</th>
                        <th> Atelier          |</th>
                        <th> Anomalie                                                
</th>

</tr>
 </thead>
 "; 

 foreach($data as $raw) {
                $destinataire=$raw['destinataire'];
                $atelier=$raw['atelier'];
                $anomalie=$raw['anomalie'];




 $mail->Body .="
 <tr>


                        <td>  ".$destinataire."</td>
                        <td>  ".$atelier." </td>
                        <td>  ".$anomalie." </td>

</tr>
</table>

      @endforeach

";
     }
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';


if(!$mail->send()) {
  echo 'Message could not be sent.';
 echo 'Mailer Error : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'destinataire' in 
/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 41

Warning: Illegal string offset 'atelier' in 
/home/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 42

Warning: Illegal string offset 'anomalie' in 
/home/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 43

Warning: Illegal string offset 'destinataire' in 
/home/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 41

Warning: Illegal string offset 'atelier' in 
/home/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 42

Warning: Illegal string offset 'anomalie' in 
/home/sendemail/sendEmail.php on line 43
Message has been sent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of `fetch()` on line 7:

```
$data = $sql->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $raw) {
    $destinataire = $raw['destinataire'];
    $atelier = $raw['atelier'];
    $anomalie = $raw['anomalie'];
}
```

Method `fetch()` returns only one next row from a result set. So, another option is to use `fetch()` in a while cycle:

```
while ($raw = $sql->fetch()) {
    $destinataire = $raw['destinataire'];
    $atelier = $raw['atelier'];
    $anomalie = $raw['anomalie'];

    // rest of your code
}
```